# Confusion in Calculating Conditional Probability mass function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

**Question:**

> If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent binomial random variables with respective 
>        parameters $(n_1,p)$ and 
>   $(n_2,p)$, calculate the conditional probability mass
>        function of $X_1$ given that, $X_1 + X_2 = m$

**My attempt:**

Letting, $q= 1-p$

$\mathbb{P}\{X_1=k\ | X_1+ X_2=m \} = \displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{P}\{X_1=k\ | X_1+ X_2=m \}}{\mathbb{P}\{X_1+ X_2=m \}}$

$=\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{P}\{X_1=k\ | X_2=m -k \}}{\mathbb{P}\{X_1+ X_2=m \}}$

$= \displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{P}\{X_1=k\ | X_2=m-k \}}{\mathbb{P}\{X_2=m-k \}}$

$= \displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{P}\{X_1=k\} \mathbb{P}\{X_2=m-k \}}{\mathbb{P}\{X_2=m-k \}}$, as $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent

$=\mathbb{P}\{X1=k\}$

$=nCk \cdot p^k \cdot (1-q)^{n_1-k}$

Can I not do this? Why? Please explain.  My text gives an elaborate solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${P\{X_1=k\ \cap X_2=m-k\} \over P\{X_1+X_2=m\}}\ne{P\{X_1=k\ \cap X_2=m-k\} \over P\{X_2=m-k\}}$$

In the denominator who said $X_1=k$?

Actually it will be $${P\{X_1=k\ \cap X_2=m-k\} \over P\{X_1+X_2=m\}}={P\{X_1=k\ \cap X_2=m-k\} \over \sum\limits_{i=1}^m P\{X_1=i\cap X_2=m-i\}}$$ 
Now sure you can do the rest...

Comment: Thanks ! I thought so that it should not be X1=k :D